# Execute curl using groovy

Tags: groovy

I have code Parser.groovy file:

```
def json = """{
        "description": "string",
        "mode": "DEFAULT",
        "name": "string",
        "start_time": "2015-11-05T13:26:40.626Z",
        "tags": [
                "string"
        ]
    }"""
    process = ["curl", "-k", "--user", "user:pass", "-X", "POST", "-H", "Content-Type: application/json", "-d", "${json}", "https://<api_uri>/launch"].execute().text
```

When I execute it, I get this exception:

```
Caught: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "curl": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "curl": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
    at Parser.run(Parser.groovy:19)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:140)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
    ... 2 more
```

What I am doing wrong? I am new at groovy, please, explain me my mistake.

Comment: It is all in the error message "The system cannot find the file specified". Where is curl ? In the path ? Some special directory ? Either set the path variable accordingly or use a full path to the exe.

Comment: Besides that: you might run into problems when handing your json over to curl. Perhaps it is better to store th JSON in a file and have curl read that file. I think it can be done with `@`

Comment: You get a recommendation for free ;-): it might involve a bit more work but if you don't want to depend on curl you can use one of the many frameworks which handle http / url in Java and call that from groovy. Have a look at http://unirest.io/java.html for example

Comment: there is no need for `"${json}"` - just use `json`. there should be no need to use a file.  `--data-binary` might also be a better choice instead of `-d`

Comment: Try using the `wslite` package, which can [post](https://github.com/jwagenleitner/groovy-wslite#sending-content) with [basic auth](https://github.com/jwagenleitner/groovy-wslite#basic-auth)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your program can not find the `curl.exe`. Either specify the full path ...

```
process = ["c:\\whatever\\curl", "-k", "--user" ...
```

... or set your environment variable `PATH` accordingly before calling your program:

```
set path=C:\whatever;%path%
```

Besides that it might be more stable to use a library for http / url communication. I am not going to recommend one but I am sure you will find lots of examples here on SO.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to do this with plain groovy and the wslite library:

```
@Grab('com.github.groovy-wslite:groovy-wslite:1.1.2')
import wslite.http.auth.*
import wslite.rest.*

def client = new RESTClient("https://<api_uri>/")
client.authorization = new HTTPBasicAuthorization("user", "pass")
def response = client.post(path: "/launch",headers: ['Content-Type': 'application/json']) {
    json description: "string", mode: "DEFAULT", name: "string", start_time: "2015-11-05T13:26:40.626Z", tags: [ "string" ] 
}
```